# Stop Android(DDMS) Profiler programmatically

Tags: android, profiler, ddms

does anybody know whether i can stop the profiler from ddms programatically? I have a bit longer process and want to stop the profile after this process is done and not manually.
Is there any method to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you can simply put the following methods in the code of your application:

```
android.os.Debug.startMethodTracing("name_of_trace");
//here you put what you want to profile
android.os.Debug.stopMethodTracing();
```

All the traces are stored on `/sdcard` You can simply use `adb pull` command to download them:

```
adb pull /sdcard/name_of_trace.trace
```

After that you can see the results using command monitor (if you use the old versions of Android tools then you should use `traceview` command. However, for newer version this command is also working):

```
monitor name_of_trace.trace
```